# implement try catch in database class php

Tags: php, class, try-catch

this here below is my class database in php

```
<?php
class DB
{

    private $SQLcommand;
    private $bd;

    public function setSQLcommand($valor)
    {
        $this->SQLcommand = $valor;
    }
    public function getSQLcommand()
    {
        return($this->SQLcommand);
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cpd", "root", "");

    }
    public function ExecSQL()
    {
        if ($this->SQLcommand != "")
            return($this->bd->exec($this->SQLcommand));
        else
            return(false);
    }   
    public function ExecSelect()
    {
        if ($this->SQLcommand != "")
        {
            $data = $this->bd->query($this->SQLcommand);
            return($data->fetchAll());


        }
        else
            return(false);
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->bd = null;
    }

}
?>
```

and here is how I instantiate

```
include_once 'db_class.php';

$e = new DB();
$e->setSQLcommand("INSERT INTO characteristic (id_charac,name_charac)
                VALUES ('','".$_POST["nomecharac"]."')");
$e->ExecSQL();


$p = new DB();
$p->setSQLcommand("select * from characteristic");                  
$data = $p->ExecSelect();
```

I would ask where in the code I can I put a try catch, that if an error occurs the try catch redirects to the file maintenance.php, and prevent the bank's User and password are showed...thank you all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put in your constructor __construct()

```
try {
    $this->bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cpd", "root", "");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Database connection could not be established.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that I'd use prepared statements; someone can put what they want into $_POST["nomecharac"] that can let them run a command that they want.

As for where to put the try-catch, if you want there to always be a redirect to maintenance.php, put it in the class. Otherwise, put it in the instantiation.

Cheers!

Comment: Good answer, especially with the prepared statements +1

Comment: could you illustrate for me ? i'll be very grateful if you did

Answer (score 1):

Your Database class should not know that your application has to redirect to a specific page, only that an exception has occurred.

1. Let Database class throw exceptions.
2. Catch the exception in your application, and take action.

Comment: could you illustrate for me  ? i'll be very grateful if you did